# Asynchronous calls with delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, asynchronous

I'm currently using delegate to make asynchronous calls in a for loop, the issue I'm running into is - how do I know when those asynchronous calls are finished?

for example:

```
         public delegate string GetMergeSectionCaller(string something1, out int threadId);

         public Dataset GetDataset (param1, param2) {
               int threadId;
               Dataset ds = new Dataset;

               using (myConnection) {
                   myConnection.StartConnection();
                   GetMergeSectionCaller caller = new GetMergeSectionCaller(GetMergeSection);
                   foreach (var r in anObjectList) {
                       IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(r.ToString(), out threadId, null, null);
                   }

                   //I want to do here is wait for the above every single foreach BeginInvoke to finish; then do the below job
                   ds = GetFinalData();
               }
               //do more thing to ds here;
               return ds;
            }

         public void GetMergeSectionCaller(string something1, out int threadId) {
             //doing superlong long job
             //in my actual case, it's actually inserting data to db etc

             Thread.Sleep(5000);
             threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
         }
```

so I tried different approaches; such as passing callback to my BeginInvoke and EndInvoke there, but still - I'm missing a way to stop the rest of the code to run before I could finish up the foreach;

maybe I'm missing something pretty simple there?.... Could someone please show me a full working sample based on my condition?

Comment: Mentioning which programming language this is would help.

Comment: just editing the title: in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. The IAsyncResult has a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) property which you can use to wait on.

```
var results = new List<WaitHandle>();
foreach (var r in anObjectList) {
   results.Add(caller.BeginInvoke(r.ToString(), out threadId, null, null).WaitHandle);
}
// wait for all results to complete
WaitHandle.WaitAll(results.ToArray());
```

Another option would be to create a ManualResetEvent and a counter and reset the event from the callback when the counter reaches 0. The advantage of this method is that you would only be creating a single waitable object but you'd have to also manage the counter.

And finally, another option would be to use the new [Task-based API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides a much better programming abstraction for waiting on tasks.

Some other things to point out:

- DO NOT use Thread.Sleep - it's ok to use it to test your code but once you've verified that your asynchronous code works, do not use it!
- DO NOT rely on the delegate BeginInvoke - that's not true parallelism. It simply defers the invocation of the method but it doesn't do what you think it does. Instead, if you want to execute those methods in parallel, use either a Task, the ThreadPool, or a Thread.

UPDATE

You may also use a TPL parallel for loop which might be closer to what you originally were hoping to achieve:

```
Parallel.ForEach(anObjectList, anObjectItem => {
    // do something with anObjectItem
});
// this parallelizes the for-loop iterations
```

UPDATE 2

Here's how to run the tasks using worker threads from the ThreadPool and a ManualResetEvent.

```
ManualResetEvent mreComplete = new ManualResetEvent(false);
int callsRemaining;

GetMergeSectionCaller caller = new GetMergeSectionCaller(GetMergeSection);
callsRemaining = anObjectList.Count;
mreComplete.Reset();
foreach (var r in anObjectList) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((Action)delegate {
        caller(r.ToString());
        lock{
           if(--callsRemaining==0) mreComplete.Set();
        }
    }
}
mreComplete.Wait();
```

Comment: woot woot!! many thanks!! I actually tried all of those you mentioned - but didn't know i could do the waitHandle as in a list. I tested and worked great!! On the other hand, I wonder if you could show me how to use ManualResetEvent as well? I tried with this a well before jumping to stackoverflow for help, but no luck; and Yes! i was testing with Parallel.ForEach for my last resort if I don't get any helps here, thanks again!!!

Comment: I'll add an example with the ManualResetEvent in combination with the TreadPool.